# How to pass and return arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, parameters

I am making a simple bank account handling system and am saving the account information as an array however I have come across difficulties when it comes to passing the account information, I am reading the array from a text file into the program but this needs to be passed from the function that reads the file to the functions that handle the withdraws, deposits and viewing the balance, the array that is passed is intended to store the current balance, a stand in for a bool for the overdraft as well as the last 3 withdraws and deposits.

the withdraw function looks like

```
float Withdraw()                                        //function handled withdraw requests
{
//variables
const int M = 3;                                //declare const int for withdraws
const int N = 8;                                //declare const int for account
float withdrawAmount = 0.0f;                    //used for internam laths in function   
float currentBalance = 0.0f;                    //used internally in function
float newBalance = 0.0f;                        //passed to write function
float withdraws[M];                             //passed to write function
float account[N];                               //passed and returned from read function
//call readFile function
readFile(account[N]);

cout << account[0];
//user interface
cout << "Withdraw opnened" << endl;                 //prompts user for input of a withdraw amount and displays current balance
cout << "Your Current Balance is: " << currentBalance << endl;
cout << "How Much Would You Like to Withdraw?" << endl;
cin >> withdrawAmount;
newBalance = currentBalance - withdrawAmount;           //calculates balance after withdraw
withdraws[2] = withdraws[1];
withdraws[1] = withdraws[0];
withdraws[0] = withdrawAmount;
system("PAUSE");
system("cls");

writeFile(newBalance, withdraws[M]);
Menu();
return 0;
}
```

and the function to read the file looks like

```
float readFile(float account[8])
{
//variables
const int N = 8;
float accountRead[N];

//read file
ifstream file("floats.txt");
if (!file.is_open())
{
    cerr << "Error opening file" << endl;
    return 0;
}
for (int i = 0; i < N && file >> accountRead[i]; ++i)
    ;
if (file)
{
}
account = accountRead;
return account[N];
}
```

any guidance would be greatly appreciated as I have spent hours trying to research this but have gotten nowhere

Comment: _'I have spent hours trying to research this'_ That sounds pretty ridiculous! Just have a look at the right side under the **Related** section.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Take it easy on him ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use `double`, not `float`. E.g. the literal `3.14` is of type `double`. That's because `double` is the default floating point type in C++, the floating point type that you use as a matter of course when there are no really weighty reasons to do otherwise.

Use `std::vector` and `std::array`, not raw arrays.

For example, you can just return a `std::vector` or `std::array` from a function.

Also, remember that

```
float readFile(float account[8])
```

is equivalent to

```
float readFile(float account[])
```

and to

```
float readFile(float* account)
```

But you don't get that problem with `std::vector` and `std::array`.

Comment: even with doing this I am still getting an error saying that I have "unresolved Externals" after some research this seems to say that I am missing an include of some kind does anyone have an idea what this could be?

Comment: Technically it means that the linker is unable to find the compiled definition of something, usually a function. Usually that's caused by not compiling and linking the source file that contains the definition (e.g., not included in the IDE "project"). In some rare cases, but less rare for novices, it's caused by a mismatch between declaration and definition -- which can be avoided by not needlessly using forward declarations of functions (which is also less work).

Answer (score 0):

```
readFile(account[N]);
```

It is wrong. You pass out-of-the-end value.

```
readFile(account);
```

That is better.

```
return account[N];
```

And you cannont return out-of-the-end value. Dereferencing pointers out of the array causes undefined behaviour.